# How to shut redis-server down when the redis-server deamon exists?

Tags: redis

After I killed the redis-server process, the redis-server deamon restarts redis-server process. How do I keep it shut down?

[image: image of shell transcript instead of actual pasted transcript]

Comment: In the future, please paste your actual shell transcript instead of an image of it, and indent each line 4 spaces so that it is formatted correctly and is legible.

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
 sudo service redis-server stop
```

to make the Redis server stop instead of kill it

Because there is maybe a sort of daemon monitor to start it automatically I believe

Answer (score 0):

Use `redis-cli` to properly shutdown since it may require `auth` key. Moreover `shutdown` command takes optional parameter `NOSAVE|SAVE` if you want to save your data before shutting down.

> redis-cli
>
> auth *auth_passowrd*
>
> shutdown SAVE